# Stanford parser with less tags

Tags: stanford-nlp

I got a parsing result as below. But I don't want some tags in this tree, for example: the NX and the last NP on top of CD-three. What i want is just the structure of the tree, not the fine-grained labels. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found NLTK support the tree very well. We can load it from string, then got what i want by collapse_unary  function. The function transform the tree by remove Collapse unary productions. Please refer the ntlk website for more information:[nltk tree](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html)